# Rapid Cross-Scene Cuts in Screenplay/Script

Tags: formatting, screenwriting

In a screenplay I'm writing, I want to use a rapid cut-together sequence of reaction shots from characters in several different locations already established earlier in the script. Is it still necessary to use the full new-scene notation for every different location? This seems a bit clumsy:

> ...
>
> The three look up as the lights flicker, and the room suddenly goes
>   dark.
>
> INT. GARAGE - DUSK
>
> We see ANDREA and PIETER, still sifting through the garage's contents,
>   as the lights flicker and go out.
>
> INT. CORRIDOR - DUSK
>
> We see SAMMY in the middle of using a crowbar to open a door; the
>   lights in the corridor flicker and go out.
>
> INT. SECURITY OFFICE - DUSK
>
> ...
>
> etc.

On the other hand, I don't want to break the normal formatting conventions. What's appropriate in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Your format is correct, although I believe you would typically place "CUT TO" above the new scene.  Screenplays have a very specific, well-established format, so it's best to stick to the conventions.  For people who are used to reading screenplays, it will seem natural, not clumsy.

Comment: Agreed that the format is correct. It does seem clumsy but it is standard. But don't "CUT TO" any of the scenes. That's a camera direction and writers leave that to directors. Also, regarding the description, I'd take out those "We see..." as that will come across as amateur. We're reading a screenplay, we know that we'll see these things. Better instead to do: ANDREA and PIETER sift through the garage's contents as the lights flicker and go out. One more thing, if you've already established those characters, don't capitalize their names.

Answer (score 0):

The smart thing to do is to add continuos to the slug line.

INT. GARAGE - NIGHT (CONTINOUS)

This indicates the action is happening at the same time as...

INT.  SECURITY OFFICE - NIGHT (CONTINOUS)